# Outlook 365 Pro Shared Mailbox weird behaviour

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, shared-mailbox

I usually don't encounter impossible to solve issues, but I am completely out of ideas here.
So here's the problem:

I want to open a shared mailbox via Outlook 365 Pro-Plus.

If I try it with:
[File>Accountsettings>New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YekAn.png)

It automatically grabs the emailadress from somewhere...
[pre-filled field (which is wrong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX7ZL.png)

which would be fine, if it worked!

**However** Outlook is just giving me the finger by **repeatedly asking for the passwort**, which, **since it's a shared mailbox, is expected and we have to "bypass" by clicking on "sign in with another account"**.


**This is the expected behaviour**, but **instead of letting us type in our own password, it already grabs a password from somewere** and then just asks for a password again..and again..
Sometimes the loop stops and says it's connecting, but then just gives us a **0x80040115** Error.

**ODDLY ENOUGH:**

Opening the shared mailbox via Webaccess https://portal.office.com
works just fine.


Now here are the things I've already tried:

1. deleted all OST-files associated with the shared-mailbox, then restarted outlook, so it would reinitiate the OST's
2. Deleted all cached credentials in Windows, then reapplied step 1
3. reinstalled Outlook 365, after deleting all cached credentials
4. reinstalled O365, after cached credentials wipe and deleting OST's
5. made sure everything's set up properly on our side (on-prem AD)
6. made sure everything's configured right in O365 via admin-panel

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 1903

Outlook: Outlook 365 Pro-Plus

I haven't looked into the event viewer, yet.

**Desired outlook behaviour:**

**A) blank field when opening/adding another mailbox


B) outlook letting me type in a password myself.**

**Any ideas or even solutions would be greatly appreciated! :)**

Some more aspects regarding out O365 setup:

-there are about 7 co-workers, for which it works fine, as it should.

-config is EXACTLY the same for each user

-shared-mailbox permissions are set via powershell, using an userarray and a for-each function.

which is basically this:

```
$automapping = $false
$users = @()
$users += "user@contoso.com"   
$users += "user1@contoso.com"

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Write-Host "Adding mailbox permission in " $mailbox " for $user " with automapping:" $automapping " 

    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $mailbox -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $automapping -User $user
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a new profile with this shared mailbox? Besides, instead of adding this shared mailbox as a second account, we can also add it as an additional mailbox via File > Account Settings. [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-and-use-a-shared-mailbox-in-outlook-d94a8e9e-21f1-4240-808b-de9c9c088afd)

Comment: Hi there, the problem was solved, forgot about this post in the meantime. So Sorry for that! So the solution was, that this marketing@contoso.com was enabled as a business account in Windows itself. (Settings >Email and App Accounts > THERE IT WAS!